# How to run docker container by giving an external file as argument

Tags: python, docker, pytest

So I have a docker project, which is some kind of Python pytest that runs subprocess on an executable file as a blackbox test. I would like to build the container, and then run it each time by copying the executable file to a dedicated folder inside the container WORKDIR (e.g. exec/). But I am not sure how to do it.

Currently, I have to first include the executable in the folder then build the container.

The structure is currently like this:

```
my_test_repo
|   |-- exec
|   |   |-- my_executable
|   |-- tests
|   |   |-- test_the_executable.py
|   |-- Dockerfile
```

I skipped over some other such as setup.

In the Dockerfile, I do the following:

```
FROM python:3.7.7-buster


WORKDIR /app    
COPY . /app

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org .
RUN pip install pytest

ENV NAME "Docker"

RUN pytest ./tests/ --executable=./exec/my_executable
```

For the last time, I setup a pytest fixture to accept the path of the executable.

I can run the test by building it:

```
docker build --tag testproject:1.0 .
```

How can I edit it so that the containers only consists of all the tests file. And it interacts with users so that I can `cp` my executable from my local dir to the container then run the test?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you know anything about the executables you're running?  Why not just `subprocess.call()` them outside of Docker?

Comment: But doesn't that mean I would also need a python environment outside of Docker? Isn't that missing that point of having a container to handle all the test ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by edit container?

you can copy the executable files from local dir to the container using docker cp command. but only one file can be copied at a time.

`docker cp path_of_executable/file_name docker_container_name:path_to_be_copy/`

Comment: Yes, I understand docker cp can do that. But I am not sure how to incorporate docker cp in. Currently, if I docker run -it, it takes me straight to python rather than bash, so I don't know how I can executable shell command. Maybe I shouldn't use the python image but use a linux image instead ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, change your Dockerfile to look like this:

```
FROM python:3.7.7-buster


WORKDIR /app    
COPY tests/ /app

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org .
RUN pip install pytest

ENV NAME "Docker"

ENTRYPOINT ["pytest", "./tests/"]
CMD []
```

Then entrypoint will be executed at runtime (*not* buildtime) along with any arguments passed in (this is handled by `CMD`.)

You can run it like this (after building it like you indicated):

```
docker testproject --executable=<path to executable>
```

The documentation for `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).

Comment: Thanks. How to copy the executable into the container if it is from my local machine?

Comment: So you want each user of the container to upload an executable into the container at run time and pass it as a flag to pytest?

Comment: You may want to consider a bash script that takes the path to the executable as an argument, creates a volume and mounts the executable within the volume, then builds and executes the container with the path to the volume built into the dockerfile. I am not sure if that would meet your requirements though.

Comment: I think that is what I need but I am afraid I don't know how to implement that. I saw another post about binding the source file to the target file in the docker-compose.yml. But I got an mapping values are not allowed here error.